# Does the WindowsCE firmware support multiple BlueTooth connections?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-ce

Can a WindowsCE device connect so more than one BlueTooth device? The device needs to both serve as a BlueTooth hands-free speaker for a phone and connect to a third device via a serial BlueTooth connection.

Can an application do this without the need of a speciel driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must understand that Windows CE is a modular OS and any specific platform capabilities are implemented by an OEM.  An OEM can create a Windows CE device with absolutely no Bluetooth support or they might choose to implement just a Bluetooth client profile (say as a bluetooth audio device) or they may choose to implement a Bluetooth server so they can consume a Bluetooth serial device.  They may also choose to implement both.  Beyond what the OEM does in software, the hardware itself might allow only one or the other (or both or neither for that matter).

The short of this is that we can't actually answer your question becasue there is no generic answer that fits all devices.  You have to ask the Device OEM what they support and if they can extend that support if they don't support what you need.

Comment: But assuming the hardware supports it - can someone confirm that the firmware supports it?

Comment: Only the OEM can confirm it.  Presence of hardware does not imply presence of capability because, as I said, CE is modular.  There's nothing in the OS that says what you want can't be done,  The question is if your OEM implemented it and only they can tell you.